# i am getting error like 'Incorrect datetime value: '-1' '

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

when trying to execute the below select query it is retrieving the data. But when i tried to store it in a temporary table its throwing 'Incorrect datetime value: '-1' error.

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE ontimecompleted
  AS
  SELECT userid AS `UserID`,
  SUM(compliant) AS `On time completion`
  FROM CompTable 
  WHERE `InUsing` = 1
  AND  ((CAST(dueDateID` AS date) -CURDATE()) <= 0)
  GROUP BY `UserID`
```

`dueDateID` is in this format : 20191101

Comment: When you run the select query - are you running it in a client that limits the amount of rows it returns? Perhaps the bad data is not seen in the top rows the client returns but then when trying to run to completion in the temporary table it does encounter bad data and throws the error.

Comment: select cast('20191101' as date) - curdate() results in -1 but I don't see how that could cause your error since you don't seem to loading any dates. What datatype is compliant?